# Python tkinter: How to make an Entry value update a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Here's my ugly little MWE/MCVE.
The code is below.

---

[image]

---

Basically, I want the `self.integer` variable (`0`) to change when the user types in the little `Entry` box.
I thought I saw something about it here, in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables), but I'm not sure. I can't make much sense of it. Also, I think there are several different ways to do it.

---

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = Tk()

        #INTEGER
        self.integer = 0

        #BUTTONS
        Button(self.main,text='Quit',command=self.main.destroy).pack()
        Button(self.main,text='+',command=self.plus_one).pack()
        Button(self.main,text='-',command=self.take_one).pack()

        #ENTRY
        Entry(self.main,textvariable=self.integer,justify=CENTER,width=4).pack()

        #MAINLOOP
        mainloop()

    def plus_one(self):
        self.integer = self.integer + 1
        self.entry0.delete(0,END)
        self.entry0.insert(0,self.integer)

    def take_one(self):
        self.integer = self.integer - 1
        self.entry0.delete(0,END)
        self.entry0.insert(0,self.integer)

Main()
```

Comment: can you add more context to your question.

Comment: Did you know Tkinter has a [Spinbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm) widget, that is basically what you're trying to create here? Also, read about Tkinter's [variables](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

Comment: @AD In the image, the value is `0`. Push the `+` button, it increases to `1`. Push the `-` button instead, it becomes `-1`. Push it again, it becomes `-2`. The button modifies the variable. And the GUI changes to reflect that. But if you manually type a number into the box, nothing happens. I want it to. If I type `128` into the box, I want the variable to change to `128`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a variable point directly to a Integer you should use `IntVar()`. The reason for this is because when you set a `textvariable` to the `Entry` Box you need to either use `IntVar()` or `StringVar()`. This will allow the value to be updated any time you type something in the Entry Box or any time you update the value of the IntVar in your code.

Take a look at this modified example of your code. I cleaned it up a bit and made it conform a little better to PEP8 standards. I also changed your `self.integer` to an `IntVar()`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #INTEGER
        self.integer = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer.set(0)
        #BUTTONS
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.destroy).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='+', command=self.plus_one).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='-', command=self.take_one).pack()
        #ENTRY
        self.entry0 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=str(self.integer), justify="center", width=4)
        self.entry0.pack()

    def plus_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() + 1
        self.integer.set(x)

    def take_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() - 1
        self.integer.set(x)

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

To check if the `IntVar()` is being updated automatically no mater how you add to the Entry box you can use a button that prints the `self.integer` to make sure this is working properly.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #INTEGER
        self.integer = tk.IntVar()
        self.integer.set(0)
        #BUTTONS
        tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.destroy).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='+', command=self.plus_one).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text='-', command=self.take_one).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Print IntVar", command=self.print_intvar).pack()
        #ENTRY
        self.entry0 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=str(self.integer), justify="center", width=4)
        self.entry0.pack()

    def plus_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() + 1
        self.integer.set(x)

    def take_one(self):
        x =  self.integer.get() - 1
        self.integer.set(x)

    def print_intvar(self):
        print(self.integer.get())

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @user3155368 Did you copy my code exactly or did you try to update your own. Also exit code 0 is an IDE output that doesn't mean much here. If you are not getting a GUI you may be trying to open this VIA the console instead of the IDE interpreter.

Comment: Hum, what IDE are you using? Python's default or something like Eclipse/Pycharm? I have tested this code in Python's default IDLE and Eclipse/PyDev IDE.

Comment: Well the main problem was you use of `textvariable`. You cannot just set a string of an intager to the `textvariable` and expect it to update as needed when you type something else. You must use a `StringVar()` or `IntVar()` method when working with the `textvariable` portion of these widgets. It just how its designed and specifically meant to be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I add to Mike solution a binding because your IntVar will not change until you press + or - button. That is not important if you use only your buttons but it will be important if you call intern methods to get IntVar value.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.main = root

    #INTEGER
    self.int_entry = IntVar() #use IntVar() instead int
    self.int_entry.set(0) #init value

    #BUTTONS
    self.button0 = Button(self.main,text='Quit',command=self.main.destroy)
    self.button0.pack()
    self.button1 = Button(self.main,text='+',command=self.plus_one)
    self.button1.pack()
    self.button2 = Button(self.main,text='-',command=self.take_one)
    self.button2.pack()

    #ENTRY
    self.entry0 = Entry(self.main,textvariable=self.int_entry,
                        justify=CENTER,width=4)
    self.entry0.pack()
    self.entry0.bind("<Enter>", self.change_value) # set value and press Enter


    def change_value(self, event):
        self.int_entry.set(self.entry0.get())

    def plus_one(self):
        s = int(self.entry0.get()) #cast to integer because Entry widget is always string object
        self.int_entry.set(s+1)

    def take_one(self):
        s = int(self.entry0.get())
        self.int_entry.set(s-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Um. I don't believe this is correct. The `IntVar()` will automatically update when you type in the entry box. You do not need to set the `IntVar()`. This is a redundant and pointless binding.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to show that the IntVar is actually auto updated weather or not you updated it with the buttons or manually.

Comment: Indeed it is so. When you set a tkinter variable to the entry then the variable will track the entry input. my bad

Answer (score -1):

Here's a minimal working example.
I made as few changes as possible.

- All changes to the code have been *`italicized`*.
- Code directly related to the question is **`bold`**.
- Omissions are *`#commented & italicized`*.
- New code is both ***`italicized & bold`***.

```
from tkinter import *

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main = Tk()

        #INTEGER
        #self.integer = 0
        self.integer = IntVar(0)

        #BUTTONS
        Button(self.main,text='Quit',command=self.main.destroy).pack()
        Button(self.main,text='+',command=self.plus_one).pack()
        Button(self.main,text='-',command=self.take_one).pack()

        #ENTRY
        Entry(self.main,textvariable=self.integer,justify=CENTER,width=4).pack()

        #MAINLOOP
        mainloop()

    def plus_one(self):
        self.integer.set(self.integer.get()+1)
        #self.entry0.delete(0,END)
        #self.entry0.insert(0,self.integer)

    def take_one(self):
        self.integer.set(self.integer.get()-1)
        #self.entry0.delete(0,END)
        #self.entry0.insert(0,self.integer)

Main()
```

[image]